# dynamically add name attribute to tags within string - react / js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

simplifying the existing post.

say I have a string

let someText = `"<h1>test</h1><p>desc of test</p>"`

I'd like to use React or javascript to change that to

someText = `"<h1 id="test">test</h1><p>desc of test</p>"`

for a table of contents type of functionality for any headers can be anchored from elsewhere on the page

I'm using react on the frontend and can also use jquery/jsdom on the backend with express

Comment: Why use the name property and not id? Also, please share the function that saves the text editor

Comment: oldskool way was name, changed it to id

Comment: Trying to get the full picture here: You are typing the above HTML in some kind of `textarea` and you want the innerHTML of the headers to be set as the value for the `id` attribute. Do you want this to happen at runtime (as you type) or when you submit the contents via some button press?

Comment: doesn't have to be runtime. just between saving the text from the textarea and to the database and rendering it back on the page

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my solution:

```js
let str = `<h1>topic 1</h1>
<p>desc of topic 1</p>

<h1>topic 2</h1>
<p>desc of topic 2</p>`;

const innerHTMLarr = str.match(/<h1>.*(?=<\/h1>)/g).map(x => x.substring(4));

const result = str.replace(/<h1>/g, function() {
  return `<h1 id="${innerHTMLarr.shift()}">`;
});

console.log(result)
```

First I match every `<h1>` in a regex. I have added a look-ahead to match the closing `</h1>` but without actually including it in the result. The same cannot be done for the opening `<h1>` since JavaScript doesn't support look-behinds (as far as I know), so we have to remove it manually with `substring()`.

Once we have the innerHTML for each `<h1>` tag, we can do a `replace()` on the whole string by finding with regex `"<h1>"` and replacing it with `"<h1 id=[x]>"`, where `x` the first result of the array we populated above. We do `shift()` here to remove used values.

**NOTE:** The above will generate an invalid `id` attribute since you can't have `spaces` in the attribute value. You may want to expand my answer for your specific use-case.

Comment: thanks for the great idea. my string wouldn't have any new line breaks, how would I update the regex? https://jsfiddle.net/nhkw85yk/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but based on your example, a simple `replace` should work fine.

```
let someText = "<h1>test</h1><p>desc of test</p>"
let idInfo = "id='test'"
let replaced = someText.replace("<h1>", `<h1 ${idInfo}>`)

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this dynamically so if a string has multiple header tags, it'll automatically determine the id based on the content within the tag and add it as its id attr